# Query including surrounding results

Tags: mysql, range, rounding

Is it possible to retrieve a range of rows using a query that gets maybe all the rows that are within 5 +or- of the query?  I figured using Round would work using a negative 2nd parameter but it doesn't seem to do it - as it ends up returning the same number anyway.

Answer (score 0):

This kind of queries are done with WINDOW FUNCTIONS!!!

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/tutorial-window.html

Should be also available for some other sql libraries